# Geometric intuition for $Z(p:q)$ in Spec $k[x,y]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Under the Zariski topology of, say, Spec $k[x,y]$, I know that $Z(p:q^\infty) = \overline{Z(p)-Z(q)}$ where $p,q$ are ideals and this intuitively makes sense to me. But is there a geometric way to view $Z(p:q)$? Or does $Z(p:q)$ get rid of too much geometric information for it to be useful / have a good interpretation by itself.

I should say that the kind of example that I had in mind was $p = (xy^2), q = (y)$ and so $p:q = (xy)$ whereas $p:q^\infty = (x)$.

Comment: If you upgrade your geometric intuition to be able to see nilpotence, I think this interpretation is still somewhat valid. In your example, $Z(p)=Z(x)+2Z(y)$, $Z(q)=Z(y)$, and $Z(p:q)=Z(x)+Z(y)=Z(xy)$. (The reason I'm writing this as a comment rather than an answer is that I'm not sure how far you can push this - it seems like this is relying a bit heavily on how nice your situation is.)

Comment: I see. That's a good way to look at it. Thanks!